# NetEncoder, Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks

I want to encode temporal data as an input for a neural net. Currently it takes in a vector of length `inputLength`. `TemporalData` does not have a out of the box encoder and I am not proficient with mathematica. I ask: How do i write such encoder?

I think a Syntax alike `NetEncoder["TemporalData", {inputLength}]` would be nice, similair to

```
imageenc =  
  NetEncoder[{"Image", {12, 12}, "ColorSpace" -> "Grayscale"}]
```

I have tried nothing and am all out of ideas. If somebody knows an approach detail will be appreciated as I am new to mathematica.

Comment: Could you gives a few examples of this 'temporal data' and what output you want from a custom NetEncoder? I don't think you've given enough information above for anyone to answer this question.

Comment: any temporal data object, which can be constructed like TemporalData[vector, {0, maxT, dt}],  where vector is a list/array/vector containing real values